# Set Alfa on ImgeView Based on Position in Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and I am populating 4 imageView. My need is that when First Item is on top visible position the  it must Alfa 1 and other items must be on 0.2f Alfa..

As I scroll my recycler view then, Item who comes on top position, it should be Set as Alfa 1. What I did..

**My Adapter**

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PageCircleIndiAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final PageModels pageModels = pageList.get(position);
    if (pageList.get(position) != null) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(pageModels.resourceId);

    }
    if (position == 0) {
        holder.rlyt.setAlpha(1f);
        pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
    }

     else if (position >firstVisible && position<lastVisible) {
        holder.rlyt.setAlpha(1f);
        pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
    } else if(position==pageList.size()-1){
        holder.rlyt.setAlpha(1f);
        pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
    }
    else {
        holder.rlyt.setAlpha(0.2f);
        pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
    }
}
```

**My MainActivity Scroll Listener **

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

            int firstVisible = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisible = manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.i("TAG", "onScrolled: " + firstVisible);
            Log.i("TAG", "Last Index: " + lastVisible);
            pageAdapter.changeItem(firstVisible, lastVisible);

        }

    });

    createIndicator();
    pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default keep the item layout alfa 0.2f in your xml layout.

Now as you are passing first visible item position to adapter in addOnScrollListener using changeItem method. In adapter make a change like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PageCircleIndiAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final PageModels pageModels = pageList.get(position);
    if (pageList.get(position) != null) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(pageModels.resourceId);

    }
    if (position == 0 || position == firstVisible) {
        holder.rlyt.setAlpha(1f);
        pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
    }else {
        holder.rlyt.setAlpha(0.2f);
        pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanxx so much.. perfect